# Converting into FLV using Java

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, flv

does anybody know how to convert any kind of video format into flv using java, i have been searching for a java api for converting video but it seems that there is no such thing but there might be a way to do it, i mean to make something like youtube service does converting the videos, but using java, i need a web application that can show videos into FLv Format but to be uploaded in any format, if somebody  has made something like this please let me know how or any idea,

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502753/programmatically-convert-a-video-to-flv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None in Java comes directly to mind, even Java's own media framework [JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) doesn't support FLV, but you may find [this overview of Open Source Flash Projects](http://www.osflash.org/open_source_flash_projects) useful. If any non-Java commandline tool turns out to be useful for you, then you could execute it from inside Java using [`Runtime#exec()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) ([tutorial here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)) or preferably [`ProcessBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) ([tutorial here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1)).

Answer (score 4):

Using xuggler, here is a simple piece of code to do exactly what you asked for:

`public class AnyMediaConverter {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        //assumes the following: arg0 is input file and arg1 is output file
        IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(args[0]);
        IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(args[1], reader);
        writer.open();
        writer.setForceInterleave(true);
        IContainerFormat outFormat = IContainerFormat.make();
        outFormat.setOutputFormat("flv", args[1], null);
        IContainer container = writer.getContainer();
        container.open(args[1], IContainer.Type.WRITE, outFormat);
        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.findEncodingCodecByName("flv"), 320, 240);
        writer.addAudioStream(1, 0, ICodec.findEncodingCodecByName("libmp3lame"), 2, 44100);
        reader.addListener(writer);
        while (reader.readPacket() == null);
    }
}`

now try doing that in JMF or FMJ or whatever (if you want a headache)

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrapper for ffmpeg that plugs into JMF: [Fobs4JMF](http://fobs.sourceforge.net/features.html)